# Move Symfony framework out from my sandbox application

Tags: symfony1

I use [Symfony Sandbox structure](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/03-Running-Symfony) in my development. Now, thinking of future ugrades, I want to separate the Symfony application out from my application and put it in a separate folder. The only problem is that it seems my application and Symfony are hopelessly intermingled together.

Anyone has any idea how to separate the Symfony engines out from my sandbox application?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this issue and blogged about it [here](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2009/05/move-symfony-framework-out-of-sandbox.html).

Answer (score 1):

After the proper [installation](http://www.symfony-project.org/installation/1_2) of symfony you just have to change the path in `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php` from

`require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/symfony/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';`

to your new symfony library directory, like this:

`require_once '/usr/share/php/symfony/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';`