# Install Pear Extension with PHP Installer

Tags: php, pear

I install PHP using the [PHP installer](http://www.php.net/downloads.php). And so, the PEAR package [is not included](http://forums.codewalkers.com/pear-packages-47/no-go-pear-bat-file-47151.html). The question now is [I need PEAR](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/03-Running-Symfony) for [Symfony upgrade purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823722/move-symfony-engines-out-from-my-sandbox-application), but the resources I found on the internet seem to cater for the case where PEAR package is already included in PHP package.

What is the best way to install PEAR extension, given that I use PHP installer for installation purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

It turns out that you have to select the PEAR option under extension menu when selecting the components for PHP installation in order to install PEAR package.

[http://lh4.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/SgBXLClDWEI/AAAAAAAAEuI/TgnBA_SEHFs/s400/pear%20install.jpg](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/Cmv4KsLwUiF4spw3tDzfHw?feat=embedwebsite)

Answer (score 1):

PEAR is just a set of libraries that ship with PHP, but you can also install PEAR manually.

While you solve the issue with your PHP installation, you can follow the instructions available at http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php under the "
PEAR in hosting environments" section.

Comment: As explained I am using the installer for PHP, so PEAR package is NOT included. You are just saying that the PEAR is there ( which is true if you use the PHP zip file but not the PHP installer)... not sure your advice solves my problem...

Comment: You can install PEAR as a library after installing PHP, installers just make your life easier, but that's not the only way to get PEAR.

Anyway, I saw that you solved your problem. Keep in mind for the next time that PEAR can be just "glued" to your PHP installation even after installing, without the need to reinstall the whole stuff.

You can get more information about this in the URL that I provided in myfirst comment.