# Why PHP CLI says php_pdo.dll cannot be found?

Tags: php

I have added php extensions directory (which contains php_pdo.dll, ...) to path environment variables, still when launching php.exe on command line, it complains it cannot find this dll and others.

What's wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you install it during the PHP installation?

[Here's how you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824050/install-pear-extension-with-php-installer/825346#825346) can do it on Windows, make sure you enable the appropriate extension.

[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/SgBXLClDWEI/AAAAAAAAEuI/TgnBA_SEHFs/s400/pear%20install.jpg](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/SgBXLClDWEI/AAAAAAAAEuI/TgnBA_SEHFs/s400/pear%20install.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Look for "extension_dir" directive from `phpinfo()` output and save your proper extension DLL to that directory.

You can change extension directory from `extension_dir` directive in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of PHP, php_pdo.dll isn't needed because it is included in the core php binary.

*However*, if you did what I did and kept your previous php.ini file when upgrading PHP, the CLI will fail because you still have the reference to the extension in your ini file uncommented.

Commenting this out will make this error go away.